# Have AVD/VDX files from a Video Security system- need a way to play them back

Tags: video, playback, dvr

I was given a disc with AVD and VDX files. There is usually one VDX file paired with the AVD File - for example, file0001.avd and file0001.vdx.

This was recorded by a security system, and we need to be able to view the video, but do not have or know what software we need to play it back.  Anyone out there know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to contact the system manufacturer for their software.  It was downloadable @ http://www.blackbox.com

Answer (score 2):

You can Download here:
http://dvr-playback.software.informer.com/
playback.exe i was used this before to play that video format.
enjoy and God bless.

Comment: There's no download link in this website.

Answer (score 0):

The first program I'd try is [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/).